# Search for a word pattern at the beginning and at the end of dataframe lines

Tags: python, dataframe, match

I am handling the following dataframe:

```
     import pandas as pd

     dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Column_01': ['Sensor with 0005-fdk', 'Sensor with RX simpleleak', 
                                             'Actuador', 'Sensor with TX xxx', 
                                             'SENSOR WITH Press OL SimplePack'], 
                               'Column_02': ['000', '001', '010', '011', '100']})
```

I need to create a new column in the dataframe above. This new column will receive the value 'DETECT' if the corresponding line in 'Column_01' starts with (Sensor with or SENSOR WITH) AND ends with (SimplePack or simplepack). Otherwise, the line will receive Nan.

I found that the function match() checks whether the regular expression matches the beginning of the text. So, I tried to implement the following code:

```
        dataframe['Column_03'] = dataframe.apply(lambda x: 'DETECT'
                                     if re.match(r'Sensor with|SENSOR WITH', x['Column_01'])
                                     else 'Nan', axis = 1)
```

However, for this problem the code is incomplete as it does not check the final regular expression.

My output is being:

```
      Column_01                   Column_02          Column_03
Sensor with 0005-fdk                 000               DETECT
Sensor with RX simpleleak            001               DETECT
Actuador                             010                Nan
Sensor with TX xxx                   011               DETECT
SENSOR WITH Press OL SimplePack      100               DETECT
```

I would like the output to be:

```
       Column_01                      Column_02          Column_03
Sensor with 0005-fdk                  000                  Nan
Sensor with RX simpleleak             001                  Nan
Actuador                              010                  Nan
Sensor with TX xxx                    011                  Nan
SENSOR WITH Press OL SimplePack       100                DETECT
```

Comment: Why use the string `'Nan'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.apply()` isn't necessary here. This solution also uses proper `NaN` values, not strings.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_01': ['Sensor with 0005-fdk', 'Sensor with RX simpleleak',
                                 'Actuador', 'Sensor with TX xxx',
                                 'SENSOR WITH Press OL SimplePack', 'Sensor with RX simplepack',
                                 'sensor With simplepack'],
                   'Column_02': ['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110']})

print(df, end='\n\n\n')

row_cond = df['Column_01'].str.casefold().str.match(r"^sensor with(?! rx).*simplepack$", case=False)

df.loc[row_cond, 'Column_03'] = 'DETECT'

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                         Column_01 Column_02
0             Sensor with 0005-fdk       000
1        Sensor with RX simpleleak       001
2                         Actuador       010
3               Sensor with TX xxx       011
4  SENSOR WITH Press OL SimplePack       100
5        Sensor with RX simplepack       101
6           sensor With simplepack       110


                         Column_01 Column_02 Column_03
0             Sensor with 0005-fdk       000       NaN
1        Sensor with RX simpleleak       001       NaN
2                         Actuador       010       NaN
3               Sensor with TX xxx       011       NaN
4  SENSOR WITH Press OL SimplePack       100    DETECT
5        Sensor with RX simplepack       101       NaN
6           sensor With simplepack       110    DETECT
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Now I have a new question.
Is it possible to look for the same start pattern (Sensor with) but if it is followed by RX (for example Sensor With RX) should it not be 'DETECT'? Thanks

Comment: @JaneBorges _(Sensor with) but if it is followed by RX (for example Sensor With RX) should it not be 'DETECT'_ I'm not sure I understand. You want strings like `'Sensor with RX ...'` to return `'DETECT'`, even if they don't end with `'SimplePack'`?

Comment: For example:
Case1: 'Sensor with Ultrassonic SimplePack' the classification would be DETECT.
Case2: 'Sensor with RX Ultrassonic SimplePack' the classification would be NAN.
Case3: 'Sensor with Ultrassonic' the classification would be NAN. Thank you

Comment: @JaneBorges Does the current solution not cover those 3 cases?

Comment: The solution is great. But I needed to change to a new problem

Comment: I want it to start with 'Sensor with' but before classifying it as a possible start I needed to check the next 3 strings (cannot be empty + RX)

Comment: @JaneBorges _I want it to start with 'Sensor with' but before classifying it as a possible start I needed to check the next 3 strings (cannot be empty + RX)_ Ooh, you want `'Sensor with'` to result in `'DETECT'`, except if it's `'Sensor with RX'`?

Comment: Something to consider together that starts with:
('sensor with') without considering
~ ('sensor with SB')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207696/discussion-between-amc-and-jane-borges).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
dataframe['Column_03']=\
dataframe['Column_01'].apply(lambda x: 'DETECT' if \
str(x).lower().startswith('sensor with')  and \
str(x).lower().endswith('simplepack') else 'Nan')
```

output:

```
                         Column_01 Column_02 Column_03
0             Sensor with 0005-fdk       000       Nan
1        Sensor with RX simpleleak       001       Nan
2                         Actuador       010       Nan
3               Sensor with TX xxx       011       Nan
4  SENSOR WITH Press OL SimplePack       100    DETECT
```

Which correspond to what *you* wrote:

"This new column will receive the value 'DETECT' if the corresponding line in 'Column_01' starts with (Sensor with or SENSOR WITH) AND ends with (SimplePack or simplepack). Otherwise, the line will receive Nan".

You expect people to help you, please at least review you question.

Comment: It does according to what you *wrote*. The example you provided contradicts what you wrote. Please check and edit your question.

Comment: this is the output from my code: 
                         Column_01 Column_02 Column_03
0             Sensor with 0005-fdk       000       Nan
1        Sensor with RX simpleleak       001       Nan
2                         Actuador       010       Nan
3               Sensor with TX xxx       011       Nan
4  SENSOR WITH Press OL SimplePack       100    DETECT

and this is what you wrote: 
 This new column will receive the value 'DETECT' if the corresponding line in 'Column_01' starts with (Sensor with or SENSOR WITH) AND ends with (SimplePack or simplepack). Otherwise- Nan. Review!!